# mongodb - can't initiate replica set with default configuration

Tags: mongodb, replication

I am following [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) tutorial to deploy a replica set. When I execute `rs.initiate()` I get the error "all members and seeds must be reachable to initiate set" which is strange given that the only member is localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
In my case the helped me:

```
cfg=rs.conf()
rs.reconfig(cfg,{force:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initiate a replica set with just one member (where do you replicate data ?!). The tutorial tells you that three active mongod instances are needed.

> Requirements: Three distinct systems, so that each system can run its own instance of mongod.

Comment: You can have a replica set with only 1 replica. [This 3-members Replica Set tutorial at docs.mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) instructs you to first create a replica set with only 1 member, by running `rs.initialize()`. And then add 2 members. — For a little while, you have a replica set with 1 member only.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, you **can** have the three members of a given replica set on the same physical machine (The tutorial mentions: "For ephemeral tests and the purposes of this guide, you may run the mongod instances in separate windows of GNU Screen.") You just need three different mongod instances running on three different ports on your machine. From the error you are getting, it seems one or the other *port* is unreachable. Just check your ports if they are already in use by some other application. If so, the respective mongod wouldn't start successfully in the first place. And therefore, rs.initiate() would fail.